# how to create a composite with a working pane in it

Tags: gwt, widget, addition, composite, gwt-designer

i'm moving my first steps with gwt to create a simple website.
i'm trying to use gwt platform and the gwt designer to create the layouts.
the site is so simple that lots of pages have the same layout and differ only for what's in the middle, so i had a "brilliant" idea: why don't u create a general layout in the form of a composite and add in the middle of this composite a simplepanel, so u can add what's different in each page just there.
i created the composite and i put a simplepanel in it, but even if i exposed the widget the gwt designer does not let me add any other widget inside this panel when i'm creating the other ui-binder views.
am i forgetting something?
thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should be going the route of trying to create your own `Composite` widget for this purpose. What you described is *exactly* what [`DockLayoutPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html) was created for. Basically, you want a (relatively) constant `north` (probably logo, possibly navigation), `south` (footer of some sort), and maybe `east`/`west` for side bars or what have you, and a `center` which changes to display the "current page". There are a great deal of examples of `DockLayoutPanel` being used in this manner- even [the Javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html) has a great one. You could easily add a panel to the `center`, and use that panel as your "main panel".

If you want to create your own `Composite` widget which can have some arbitrary children widgets *and* be used by GWT Designer, you've got a lot of work ahead of you.

Comment: u perfectly understood what i need, and i know the dockpanel works like that... but if i could have a general, already popolated dockpanel with only the center to add, i could modify only my general composite and all my pages would take the mods...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a [Composite](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.html) used in UiBinder that behaves like a panel, you'll have to create a custom element parser for it, but the problem is that there's no public API for doing this in GWT (as of 2.4.0). Maybe [gwt-customuibinder](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-customuibinder/) can help with that. The alternative is to implement [HasWidgets](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.html) since there's a built-in [parser](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/uibinder/elementparsers/HasWidgetsParser.java) for that.